# Limit number of simultaneous queries by user

Tags: postgresql, users, role, limits

I am looking for way to allow one user to execute maximum 3 queries at the time. Is there such possibility in Postgres?

Due to some technial difficulties I cant limit number of connections, and the solution should be based on limit of simultaneus queries or something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible now. You have two classes of configuration options

- [Connections and Authentication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html), includes things like `max_connections`
- [Session/Client Configuration](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html), includes things like `statement_timeout`, `lock_timeout`, `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout`
- [Role-based settings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-alterrole.html) includes `CONNECTION LIMIT` (per user).

That's all that the server provides. In order to track what you're talking about the server would have to check `pg_stat_activity`. You can however get the information you're looking for manually..

```
SELECT usename AS username, count(*) AS concurrent_statements
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE state = 'active'
GROUP BY usename;
```

You can run a function periodically that checks the above and calls `pg_cancel_backend(pid int)`, or `pg_terminate_backend(pid int)`. See the [docs here for more information](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html) I don't particularly think that's a good idea. I would work with the default options before I tried to roll my own system based on this.